# Remove duplicates by line, based on specific columns

Tags: excel, sorting, duplicates

I have a spreadsheet with six columns, and I want to remove duplicates for each line which contains values within columns 3 and 4 that match the values of 3 and 4 on another line. For example, these two lines would need to be deduped:

```
alpha.txt, beta.txt, 03/12/15, exit, gamma.txt, bravo.txt
gamma.txt, bravo.txt, 03/12/15, exit, alpha.txt, beta.txt
```

Since columns 3 and 4 match, I want these to be deduped. I tried using the Data > Remove Duplicates feature within Excel (selecting the entire table but removing duplicates only by columns 3 and 4) but it fails to remove all of the duplicates.

Does anyone have an alternative method in Excel or perhaps via sort or some other Linux utility?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying; I want one row remaining.

Comment: http://imgur.com/11lPKQ9

These four values remain, whereas only two should remain after using Remove Duplicates with columns 3 and 4 checked off.

Comment: Can you post a worksheet with the actual lines that won't respond?  It may be that there are hidden characters, or some other subtle difference not apparent on the screenshot.